# Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure) - Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to test database but it is giving me Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure) error.

```
Response message:java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure)
```

Jdbc connection configuration:

```
database url: 
jdbc:mysql://codebytenepal.com.np:3306/database_cbn
```

In order to test whether I'm doing anything wrong or not, I created test db in db4free.net and it worked perfectly.

```
database url in jdbc connection: 
jdbc:mysql://db4free.net:3306/shrestha
```

This works but the above doesn't. What might be the reason?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The host you're trying to reach doesn't have port 3306 open as it evidenced by [Nmap](https://nmap.org/) report

```
root@af33db8ee27e:/# nmap codebytenepal.com.np

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-10-13 15:53 UTC
Nmap scan report for codebytenepal.com.np (192.3.201.45)
Host is up (0.0016s latency).
Not shown: 965 filtered ports
PORT      STATE  SERVICE
21/tcp    open   ftp
22/tcp    closed ssh
25/tcp    open   smtp
26/tcp    open   rsftp
53/tcp    open   domain
80/tcp    open   http
110/tcp   open   pop3
143/tcp   open   imap
443/tcp   open   https
587/tcp   open   submission
993/tcp   open   imaps
995/tcp   open   pop3s
8080/tcp  closed http-proxy
8443/tcp  closed https-alt
8888/tcp  open   sun-answerbook
49152/tcp closed unknown
49153/tcp closed unknown
49154/tcp closed unknown
49156/tcp closed unknown
49157/tcp closed unknown
49159/tcp closed unknown
49160/tcp closed unknown
49165/tcp closed unknown
49175/tcp closed unknown
49400/tcp closed compaqdiag
50000/tcp closed ibm-db2
51103/tcp closed unknown
52822/tcp closed unknown
54045/tcp closed unknown
54328/tcp closed unknown
55056/tcp closed unknown
55600/tcp closed unknown
56737/tcp closed unknown
62078/tcp closed iphone-sync
65129/tcp closed unknown
```

For the other host port 3306 is open:

```
root@af33db8ee27e:/# nmap -F db4free.net

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-10-13 15:58 UTC
Nmap scan report for db4free.net (85.10.205.173)
Host is up (0.016s latency).
Not shown: 96 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
3306/tcp open  mysql

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 16.49 seconds
```

So it's absolutely expected that you cannot establish to the connection to codebytenepal.com.np:3306 as it is not open to the world.

If you absolutely need to test it you need to:

1. [Bind the database server to listen on](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-allow-remote-mysql-database-connection) 192.3.201.45 address
2. Open port 3306 in your [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing))

however be aware that it opens a [big security hole](https://serverfault.com/questions/19945/the-wisdom-of-exposing-a-database-server-on-the-internet/19961) in your deployment so revert the changes after you're done with your testing

More information: [MySQL Database and JMeter - How to Test Your Connection](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mysql-database-and-jmeter-how-to-test-your-connection)